# validate fields where field name suffixed with number in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have dynamically created element in JQuery where i have assigned controls name as location_1,location_2,location_3, floor_1, floor_2,floor_3 and so on. It was not possible to use html-control array because these all fields are interdependent. So for me the ultimate solution was suffixing number. 
Now i want to validate these fields where rules should looks something like

```
    ['location_*' => 'required|exists:locations,id'],
    ['Floor_*' =>    'required|exists:floor,id']
```

how can i do this so that i could get an error back if it failed?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to loop over the request data and create rules based on the locations and floors you find. For instance for floors, given your example:

```
$rules = [...] // initialise your rules array here
$locationRule = 'required|exists:locations,id';
foreach ($request->all() as $input) {
    if (preg_match('@^location_@', $input) {
        $rules[$input] = $locationRule;
    }
}
```